# Avoid multiple http calls on pressing enter button multiple times

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a button which makes an API call on keyboard enter. If they enter instantly multiple times, it would make 'n' no. of calls.

How to avoid this with a clean generic solution, so that it can be used everywhere?

```
    <button click="initiateBulkPayment()(keyup.enter)="initiateBulkPayment">

    initiateBulkPayment = (orderId:any, payment_methods:any) => {
       let postParams = payment_methods;
       console.log('this is payment_method', payment_methods);


       return this.http.post(Constants.API_ENDPOINT + '/oms/api/orders/' + 
           orderId + '/payments/bulk_create/', postParams, this.auth.returnHeaderHandler())
          .pipe(map((data: any) => {
           return data;
       }),
       catchError((err)=>{
         return throwError(err);
       }));
   }
```

Comment: `shareReply` will allow you to multicast the response, but to prevent to actually call it, you have to have some mechanism outside and the `isProccessed` is the typical way.

Comment: cant you just disable the button when a request is being processed?

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

1. Disable the button while the call is being executed
2. Skip the excess calls

**Disable the button while the call is being executed:**

```html
<button [disabled]="paymentRequest.inProgress$ | async" (click)="onPayButtonClick()">
```

```js
export class ProgressRequest {
    private _inProgress$ = new UniqueBehaviorSubject(false);

    execute<TResult>(call: () => Observable<TResult>): Observable<TResult> {
        if (!this._inProgress$.value) {
            this._inProgress$.next(true);
            return call().pipe(
                finalize(() => {
                    this._inProgress$.next(false);
                })
            );
        } else {
            throw new Error("the request is currently being executed");
        }
    }

    get inProgress$(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this._inProgress$;
    }
}

@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent {
    readonly paymentRequest = new ProgressRequest();

    onPayButtonClick() {
        this.paymentRequest.execute(() => {
            return this.http.post(
                Constants.API_ENDPOINT + '/oms/api/orders/' + orderId + '/payments/bulk_create/',
                postParams,
                this.auth.returnHeaderHandler()
            ).pipe(map((data: any) => {
                return data;
            });
        }).subscribe(data => {
            console.log("done!", data);
        });
    }
}
```

**Skip the excess calls:**

You can use [exhaustMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/exhaustmap.html) to skip requests while the previoius one is being executed. Note that `switchMap` and `shareReplay`, which was suggested in other answers won't prevent excess http calls.

```html
<button #paymentButton>
```

```js
@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('paymentButton', { static: true })
    readonly paymentButton!: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

    ngOnInit() {
        merge(
            fromEvent(this.paymentButton.nativeElement, 'click'),
            fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(this.paymentButton.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
                filter(event => event.key === "Enter")
            )
        ).pipe(
            exhaustMap(() => {
                return this.http.post(
                    Constants.API_ENDPOINT + '/oms/api/orders/' + orderId + '/payments/bulk_create/',
                    postParams,
                    this.auth.returnHeaderHandler()
                ).pipe(map((data: any) => {
                    return data;
                });
            })
        ).subscribe(result => {
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
}
```

Note that `click` event is fired also when you press the `enter` key, so it isn't necessary to listen 'keyup'.

```js
// You can replace
merge(
    fromEvent(this.paymentButton.nativeElement, 'click'),
    fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(this.paymentButton.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
        filter(event => event.key === "Enter")
    )
)

// just by
fromEvent(this.paymentButton.nativeElement, 'click')
```

Comment: Is there way we can prevent in HTTP interceptors in the script globally, rather than dwelling in HTML button changes.

Comment: @sharathsubramanya Anyway you should change the DOM somehow to prevent the interaction. Usually it's better to disable the only button instead of blocking the whole user interaction. I've added a code sample to the answer, how you can disable the button, this approach is the best in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. I'll try this out.

Answer (score 1):

The most self-contained approach that I could think of is using a directive to extend the functionality of a button element.

The idea is that the button can map its click event into an inner stream, and ignore all subsequent click events until the inner stream completes.

This can be done as follows:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, isObservable, of, fromEvent, Subscription, empty } from 'rxjs';
import { exhaustMap, tap, take, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

export type ButtonHandler = (e?: MouseEvent) => Observable<unknown> | Promise<unknown>;

const defaultHandler: ButtonHandler = (e) => empty();

@Directive({
  selector: 'button[serial-btn]',
  exportAs: 'serialBtn',
  host: {
    '[disabled]': 'disableWhenProcessing && _processing'
  }
})
export class SerialButtonDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  private _processing = false;
  private _sub = Subscription.EMPTY;

  @Input()
  disableWhenProcessing = false;

  @Input()
  handler: ButtonHandler = defaultHandler;

  get processing(): boolean { return this._processing };

  constructor(private readonly btnElement: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._sub = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.btnElement.nativeElement, 'click')
      .pipe(
        exhaustMap(e => this.wrapHandlerInObservable(e))
      ).subscribe();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._sub.unsubscribe();
  }

  private wrapHandlerInObservable(e: MouseEvent) {
    this._processing = true;
    const handleResult = this.handler(e);
    let obs: Observable<unknown>;
    if (isObservable(handleResult)) {
      obs = handleResult;
    } else {
      obs = of(handleResult);
    }
    return obs.pipe(take(1), finalize(() => this._processing = false));
  }
}
```

You could them use it as:

```
<button serial-btn [handler]="handler">Handle</button>

import {timer} from 'rxjs';
import {ButtonHandle} from './directive-file';

handler: ButtonHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    return timer(3000);
  }
```

A live demo can be found in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/serialbtn)

Comment: Great solution! You could add `OnDestroy` to the `implements` statement.

Comment: Instead of `take(1)`, I use `ignoreElements()` to support `EMPTY`/`Observable<never>` as well.

Comment: `of(handleResult)` --> `from(handleResult)`

Answer (score 1):

Make an attribute directive firstly,you can set the time for blocking aswell,

```
 @Directive({
          selector: '[preventMultipleCalls]'
        })
        export class PreventApiCallsDirective implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
        
          @Input('time') throttleTimeValue = 10000 
          @Output('emit') fireCallEventEmitter :EventEmitter<boolean>= new EventEmitter<boolean>();
          clickObservable = new Observable<Event>();
          clickSubscription: Subscription;
        
          constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
            this.clickObserable = fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement,'keyup')
           }
        
          ngOnInit(): void {
            this.clickSubscription = this.clickObserable.pipe(filter((e :any) => e.keyCode === 13),
               throttleTime(this.throttleTimeValue))
              .subscribe(event => {
                this.fireCallEventEmitter.emit(true)
              });
          }
        
          ngOnDestroy(): void {
            this.clickSubscription?.unsubscribe();
          }
        
        }
```

And place that directive like this on the button:

```
<button preventMultipleCalls (emit)="initiateBulkPayment()"> </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Directive that disables the button for a given amount of time.

```
// debounce.directive.ts
import { Directive, OnInit, HostListener, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDebounce]'
})
export class DebounceDirective {
  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>,
  ) { }

  @Input() appDebounce: number;

  @HostListener('click') onMouseEnter() {
    this.el.nativeElement.disabled = true;
    setTimeout(() => this.el.nativeElement.disabled = false, this.appDebounce)
  }
}

// component.ts
<button [appDebounce]="1000" click="initiateBulkPayment()(keyup.enter)="initiateBulkPayment">
```

See this [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6x2hag)

Comment: What if the request is completed in two seconds?

Comment: @ValeriyKatkov My target is to prevent an accidental click, Not a deliberate one.

Comment: Is there way we can prevent in HTTP interceptors in the script globally, rather than dwelling in HTML button changes?

Answer (score -1):

You can disable/enable the button to prevent click event or use shareReplay rxjs operator

```
return this.http.post(Constants.API_ENDPOINT + '/oms/api/orders/' + 
         orderId + '/payments/bulk_create/', postParams, 
         this.auth.returnHeaderHandler())
       .pipe(map((data: any) => {
               return data;
            }
        ),
        shareReplay(1)
        catchError((err)=>{
          return throwError(err);
        }));
```

Docs link: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html

Comment: shareReplay won't prevent multiple http requests executed

Comment: shareReplay won't block the call. This still makes multiple calls. Tried it.